# Problem with light

Tags: electrical

I been having a problem with my light , my air conditioning from my room is on and the one from the living room they fight to get energy theres a moment where one gets more and the oner one dosent also if i use my washer all my light dim and flicker or if i turn my microwave on all my light goes down i can put something on the microwave on 6 min to heat and when i take it out is still cold does anyone know what is the problem

Comment: Please revise your post to punctuate that long string into complete sentences using periods and capital letters. It's hard to understand what you're saying.

Comment: It sounds like you simply [need more power](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qs-ANd7ZncQ) But seriously: Is this a rental or do you own? Do you have access to an electric panel ("breaker box")? How many circuits do you have?

Comment: Have you always had these problems? Or did things work OK in the past (yesterday or a week or a month ago) and now they don't work any more?

Answer (score 5):

### Call the power company and report an outage!

Specifically a **Lost Neutral**.

This situation of two loads (on different circuits) "competing" for voltage and affecting the voltage of everything else, with some appliances not getting enough power and others getting fried, is a classic symptom of a **lost neutral**.

It's as simple as that. Don't make it complicated.

Utility power in North America is delivered as 240V with a "neutral" in the middle, giving two poles of 120+120.  If you lose either pole, half your 120V circuits go out.  **However, if you lose a neutral, it's still 240V but it's not 120+120 anymore!**  Instead they are 100+140, 90+150, 180+60, the voltages jump madly all over the map everytime something cycles on (like an A/C).

**The power company will treat this exactly the same as a power outage**.  And it will be free to fix.   This happened at my apartment complex, and the power company was out in an hour on a Sunday.

In the meantime, RIGHT NOW turn off all your breakers except water heater (that one is immune to this problem). If  you're unwilling to do that based on some guy on the Internet (who has 80,000 reputation here), then unplug any appliances you don't want destroyed. *This situation is **extremely unstable**, and the voltage will keep moving all over the place and you'll never be able to stabilize it enough to use appliances safely. So don't even try; it can't be done.*

Phone the power company ASAP and report a lost neutral.

Comment: Good point. Just very confusing to me from the original question whether this is "I *always* have these problems, my power is consistently not good enough" or whether this is "Used to work fine and **now** I have these crazy problems" - if it is the latter then you are likely correct.

Comment: @manassehkatz wouldn’t matter. I was shocked to realize how long it can take to discover a lost neutral problem, when we had one at my own complex.  I only found out after my sweetie apologized for the waffles taking twice as long as usual to toast...  and my eyebrows shot up.  Further inquiry found a neighbor's microwave had inexplicably fried, and   **the symptoms first appeared a week prior** and *we all* missed it.

Comment: @Harper well, don't be too hard on yourself.  Stuff that is "sort of working" is really hard to diagnose.